# Collapse button showing up in between links on medium screen

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, bootstrap-5

I'm struggling with getting the navbar elements in the right order.
On small screens (phone) the collapse button shows up on top of the links, but for some reason on medium screens it shows up before the last link in the menu. Anyone has a solution to this and tell me what's causing this? Many thanks in advance!

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/laurent-bosteels/pen/qBRKQor

HTML

```
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-1 order-md-0 dual-collapse2">

          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">DISCOVER</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">PRICING</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="mx-auto order-0">
          <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand d-none d-lg-block me-auto" alt="logo" aria-label="ad astra logo">

            <svg class="logo" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 231.1 160.4"
              enable-background="new 0 0 231.1 160.4" xml:space="preserve">
              <g>
                <path class="logo-fill" fill="#959595" d="M228.6,0h-12.5c-1.8,0-3.1,1.2-3.7,3.5l-11.7,36.4h-60.3L128.7,3.5C128.2,1.2,127,0,125.2,0h-12.7
        c-2.2,0-2.9,1.2-2.2,3.5l46.6,153.4c0.7,2.3,2.2,3.5,4.7,3.5h17.9c2.5,0,4.1-1.2,4.7-3.5L230.8,3.5C231.5,1.2,230.8,0,228.6,0z
         M171,141.7h-1l-25.7-86.3h52.3L171,141.7z" />
                <path class="logo-fill" fill="#959595" d="M74.2,3.5C73.6,1.2,72,0,69.5,0H51.6c-2.5,0-4.1,1.2-4.7,3.5L0.2,156.9c-0.7,2.3,0.1,3.5,2.2,3.5h12.5
        c1.8,0,3.1-1.2,3.7-3.5l11.7-36.4h60.3l11.7,36.4c0.5,2.3,1.7,3.5,3.5,3.5h12.7c2.2,0,2.9-1.2,2.2-3.5L74.2,3.5z M34.4,105L60,18.7
        h1L86.7,105H34.4z" />
              </g>
            </svg>
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".dual-collapse2">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
.navbar-custom {
  background-color: #0D1521;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand,
.navbar-custom .navbar-text {
    color: #F8F9F9;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 1.15rem;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(46 57 67);
}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please fix it into a [mcve]

Comment: https://codepen.io/laurent-bosteels/pen/qBRKQor
thank you! :)

Comment: Please click edit, scroll down, click edit above snippet. External links go stale, disappear or a changed to no longer reflect the issue.

Comment: Your codepen also shows a blank screen

Comment: @mplungjan strange, it is working here. The navbar is on the bottom of the page, pretty hard to miss since the codepen footer has the same color. Appreciate the help since i'm all new to this

Comment: So now you removed the snippet I made you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you’re looking to do is to have the collapse button at the top of the menu when it’s open, then you could put the button at the start of the navbar. Then, when it’s clicked, the button will move up the screen to show the menu.

The order-0, -1, -3 didn’t seem to be doing anything, so I took those out.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<style>
    .navbar-custom {
        background-color: #0D1521;
    }

    .navbar-custom .navbar-brand,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-text {
        color: #F8F9F9;
    }

    .navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
        padding: 0;
    }

    .nav-link {
        font-size: 1.15rem;
        margin-right: 2rem;
        margin-left: 2rem;
        padding-top: 0.5rem;
        padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
    }

    .navbar-nav .nav-item:not(:last-child) {
        border-right: 1px solid rgb(46 57 67);
    }
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <button class="navbar-toggler mx-auto" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".dual-collapse2">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-md-0 dual-collapse2">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">DISCOVER</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">PRICING</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand d-none d-lg-block me-auto" aria-label="ad astra logo">

            <svg class="logo" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 231.1 160.4" enable-background="new 0 0 231.1 160.4" xml:space="preserve">
                <g>
                    <path class="logo-fill" fill="#959595" d="M228.6,0h-12.5c-1.8,0-3.1,1.2-3.7,3.5l-11.7,36.4h-60.3L128.7,3.5C128.2,1.2,127,0,125.2,0h-12.7
    c-2.2,0-2.9,1.2-2.2,3.5l46.6,153.4c0.7,2.3,2.2,3.5,4.7,3.5h17.9c2.5,0,4.1-1.2,4.7-3.5L230.8,3.5C231.5,1.2,230.8,0,228.6,0z
    M171,141.7h-1l-25.7-86.3h52.3L171,141.7z" />
                    <path class="logo-fill" fill="#959595" d="M74.2,3.5C73.6,1.2,72,0,69.5,0H51.6c-2.5,0-4.1,1.2-4.7,3.5L0.2,156.9c-0.7,2.3,0.1,3.5,2.2,3.5h12.5
    c1.8,0,3.1-1.2,3.7-3.5l11.7-36.4h60.3l11.7,36.4c0.5,2.3,1.7,3.5,3.5,3.5h12.7c2.2,0,2.9-1.2,2.2-3.5L74.2,3.5z M34.4,105L60,18.7
    h1L86.7,105H34.4z" />
                </g>
            </svg>
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 dual-collapse2">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you SO much for this, it looks pretty clear to me now. I was holding on to the classic navbar html and didnt know I could change the elements order! Have a nice day.